# Is there a way to quickly navigate to the Pokedex entry for pokemon I'm carrying with me?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Since I'm often trying to complete research for the Pokemon I'm carrying around with me, I frequently find myself wanting to check their Pokedex entries.  However, as my Pokedex grows in size, I've found that navigating the Pokedex entry for the Pokemon I'm carrying around with me is becoming increasingly tedious and annoying to do. I assumed there'd either be a "View Pokedex Entry" accessible via the menu or a "Sort by Carrying" option in the Pokedex, but neither seems to exist,  although I could just be overlooking something.

**Is there a way to quickly and easily navigate the Pokedex entry for Pokemon I'm carrying around with me?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, no. There's no such option.

Not a real solution, but since you are carrying Pokemon with a low Research level your best bet is to sort the list by Research level. Doing that you'll get all Pokemon with the incomplete Dex page at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no; that’s not true in any Pokémon game, at least not any I’m familiar with. Pokémon games don’t connect the Pokédex with the party.  Neither Sword/Shield nor Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl have such a connection. They have some information from the Pokédex on the summary page, just as in Pokémon Legends: Arceus, but no link.

Of course, this is the first game in a while that needed such a link due to the research category; it’s unfortunate they did not link them not add a sort or filter function.